# Expo error when trying to global install CLI after update

Tags: expo

After I started Expo, I got the message I was running an a older version of the client and asked me to run `npm install -g expo-cli` , so I foolishly did.

After the install was finished I ran `expo start` and got the following question:

```
This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]?
```

To what I replied with: `Y` and got the following respond:

```
Installing the package 'expo-cli'...
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:235:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I've tried:

```
expo diagnostics
```

But am met with the same response.

**Anyone knows how I can solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my laptop and ran `npm install -g expo-cli` this somehow solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

A quick around would be to remove expo and expo.cmd in node_modules/.bin since it seems to be using the expo in node_modules/.bin and not the global one.